# "not so expensive as" vs "not as expensive as"

Tags: comparison

> Dinner wasn’t **so expensive as** I expected.
>
> Dinner wasn’t **as expensive as** I expected.

As I understand these sentences, they are the same in their meaning, but the second one is more common. On the other hand, maybe, there is some difference?

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko, If there is no difference in meaning, it answers. Thanks.